# Plot marginal for x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to get some plot marginals on the x-axis using dates, because the bars at the ends are cliped. But I don't want to use a larger date span on the axis. I have tried using set_xmargin() without luck. How do I solve this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

today = datetime.date.today()

imsiDate = [datetime.date(2016, 1, 11), datetime.date(2016, 1, 14), datetime.date(2016, 1, 18), ]
imsiUp = [13, 6, 24]
imsiDown = [4, 23, 1]

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.set_xmargin(0.75)
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale_view()

ax.yaxis.grid()
plotUp = ax.bar(imsiDate, imsiUp, width=0.75, color='r', align='center')
plotDown = ax.bar(imsiDate, imsiDown, width=0.75, color='y', align='center', bottom=imsiUp)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.DayLocator())

#limits
t0 = today - datetime.timedelta(7) 
t1 = today
ax.set_xbound(t0, t1)

plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to call `ax.autoscale_view()` after setting the margins an after the plotting. (0.75 is a lot of margin, though!)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

today = datetime.date.today()

imsiDate = [datetime.date(2016, 1, 11), datetime.date(2016, 1, 14), datetime.date(2016, 1, 18), ]
imsiUp = [13, 6, 24]
imsiDown = [4, 23, 1]

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.xaxis_date()

ax.yaxis.grid()
plotUp = ax.bar(imsiDate, imsiUp, width=0.75, color='r', align='center')
plotDown = ax.bar(imsiDate, imsiDown, width=0.75, color='y', align='center', bottom=imsiUp)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.DayLocator())

#limits
t0 = today - datetime.timedelta(7) 
t1 = today
ax.set_xbound(t0, t1)

ax.set_xmargin(0.75)
ax.autoscale_view()                    # <----  THIS
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

plt.show()
```

[image]